# Where can I get an app/plugin that measures the tone/attitude of an email?

Tags: email

I'm looking for a way to measure the tone/attitude of a body of text, specifically email. Something that indicates if the email is hostile, friendly, rude, polite, condescending, and/or other similar things.

I have a friend that used the outlook plugin from tonecheck.com in the past, but their website authentication appears to be broken, so I can't download anything. A way to get their app/plugin would probably be a solution(hosted elsewhere, trick to logging in, etc).

I'm looking for a plugin for gmail, but can also use outlook if needed. Worst case, its a standalone app that you copy/paste text into.

Comment: Are you trying to measure the tone of your outgoing e-mails, or of incoming emails?

Comment: @MichaelKohne outgoing emails, that I've composed. A standalone app would work too though.